# Is there a component for a data grid like the one Notion and Airtable use?

Tags: gridview, datagrid, airtable

The data grid that [Notion](https://www.notion.so) and [Airtable](http://www.airtable.com) use for their table/database view is very nice and full of great features (like type specific columns, resizing, being beautiful, fast, excel-like):

[image: notion's data grid]

[image: Airtable's table view]

Is there a component (free or paid) that does the same as those (in that beautiful and fast way)? Or are they built internally by Notion/Airtable?

Answer (score 1):

They probably use a custom one but there's this open source one from [Glide](https://grid.glideapps.com/) that is similar.